# jQuery get HTML of div with display:none

Tags: jquery

How can I get the html of a div with the style "display:none"?

I tried it with .html() but it doesn't work:

```js
document.writeln($('#teilnahmecontent').html());
```

```html
<div id="teilnahmecontent" style="display:none"><p>testcontent</p></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yf328bmL/

It only works when I remove the display:none

Comment: Your example doesn't work because you haven't loaded the jQuery library. Working version: https://jsfiddle.net/yf328bmL/2/

Comment: Using `document.writeln()` is weird, better use e.g. `console.log()` because you are now overwriting the document.

Comment: @Turnip why undo my edit that made jQuery work? it seems obvious that OP does not know how to do so, so I did it for them. You are taking focus away from the actual problem.

Comment: Just add jquery and it will work perfectly

Comment: @PeterB Because adding jQuery to OPs code would remove the problem. Fixing code within the question would make the question invalid. The problem should be solved in an answer. Or in a situation like this; just close as _"a problem that can no longer be reproduced "_

Comment: okay thank you, but why does it work without loading jQuery when I remove the "display:none"?

Comment: It doesn't. You are just showing the DIV that is already in your HTML. Your Javascript is doing nothing but throwing a reference error (look at the console).

Comment: okay thank's a lot!

Comment: `display: none` only sets the style of the element to not be visible. However the element is still there, so you can still retrieve all the data of the element. Therefore the function `html()` is the jQuery function to get the html within the element even when it's not displayed.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the various divs and iterate over it using jquery (or querySelectorAll() if you want a jQuery free solution) . Then if the style of the div === 'none' - console log the text content. I added a second div that does not have the display: none style to demonstrate. Also - its better to separate your CSS and html so I have put the display none ion the css portion of the snippet.

```js
var divs= $('div');

divs.each(function(div){
  var div = $(this);

  if(div.css('display') == 'none') {
    var content = div.text().trim();
    console.log(content); // gives "testcontent" - the content of the hidden div
  }
})
```

```css
#teilnahmecontent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="teilnahmecontent">
  <p>testcontent</p>
</div>
<div id="teilnahmecontent2">
  <p>testcontent 2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to find hidden element like div

$( "div:hidden")